# spring integration startup error

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I got this error in the console:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'T(org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationContextUtils).getIntegrationProperties(beanFactory).getProperty('spring.integraton.channels.autoCreate')' in string value "${T(org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationContextUtils).getIntegrationProperties(beanFactory).getProperty('spring.integraton.channels.autoCreate')}"

using spring integration 4.1.5.RELEASE

```
<int:channel id="mailChannel"/>

<int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="emailReceiverAdapter"
                                  store-uri="imaps://username:password@imap.mail.yahoo.com:993/inbox"
                                  channel="receiveChannel"
                                  auto-startup="true"
                                  should-delete-messages="false"
                                  should-mark-messages-as-read="false"
                                  java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
                                  max-fetch-size="1">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="10000"/>
</int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="mailReceiver" class="com.company.email.EmailReceiver"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="receiveChannel" ref="mailReceiver" method="process"/>

<util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imap</prop>
    <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
</util:properties>
```

in the test everything runs ok, but when I start the app, I got error above.

Answer (score 1):

Found this in the spring integration migration guide

> Spring Integration starting with version 3.0 introduced global
>   options, which can be changed using META-INF/integration.properties
>   file or integrationGlobalProperties bean. Since version 4.0 those
>   properties have been enriched with spring.integraton. prefix. Here is
>   a list of all supported global options with their default values:
>
> spring.integraton.channels.autoCreate=true
>   spring.integraton.channels.maxUnicastSubscribers=0x7fffffff
>   spring.integraton.channels.maxBroadcastSubscribers=0x7fffffff
>   spring.integraton.taskScheduler.poolSize=10
>   spring.integraton.messagingTemplate.throwExceptionOnLateReply=false

So the kind of error that you're getting it seems like you'll have to create this property file and put it the appropriate location mentioned. You can check the link [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-3.0-to-4.0-Migration-Guide)
One example is also given [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/1f91d4b8321dca7bbef48022cac56c765646a84e/spring-integration-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/config/xml/propertyplaceholder/PropertyPlaceholderTests-context.xml)

```
<context:property-placeholder
    location="org/springframework/integration/config/xml/propertyplaceholder/channel.properties" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I try that, and didn't help.I guess was something with version of spring which I'm using 3.2.7, so I downgraded spring integration to 2.x, and now is working.